# clarification for a design/develop system with many to many relationship in java

Tags: java, uml

If we have many to many relationship we break them in to 1-m by introducing a reference table and that should be depict in the ER diagram.

For example if Item and Order is m-m we introduced ItemOrder reference table.

But while developing the system, do we identify ItemOrder as a entity (a domain class) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no and maybe.

Would you have an `ItemOrder` class? Maybe!

Would it be a "domain class"? *No* it would not. The keyword in domain class is *domain*. What constitutes a *domain* class depends on how your stakeholders perceive the domain. In this case, they probably have never thought of an "Item Order" - there's just an Order and it has a relationship with Items. "Order" and "Item" are relevant domain concepts because they are familiar to your stakeholder; "Item Order" is not.

But you might have an `ItemOrder` class anyways - but it's probably internal. For example, if you're using [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) objects your `Order` class might look like this:

```
public class OrderRDG {

    private UUID orderId;

    public static OrderRDG[] find() { /* SQL code etc... */ }
    public static OrderRDG[] findById() { /* SQL code etc... */ }

    public UUID getOrderId() { return orderId; }

    public Item getItems() {
        ItemRDG[] items = []; // yes, I know Java arrays don't work like this - it's only an example
        OrderItemRDG[] orderItems = OrderItemRDG.findItemsByOrderId(orderId);
        for(OrderItemRDG orderItem:orderItems) {
            ItemRDG item = ItemRDG.findById(orderItem.getItemId());
            items.push(item);
        }
        return items;
    }

}
```

Comment: Another question is do we need to have a one to one field map with a table in data base and the entity class?